# How do you implement commit-hooks on a repository hosted on a remote server

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I created a repository on my remote server through TortoiseSVN, and I have a local working copy of that repository on my linux machine. So how do I implement my hooks? I can't seem to find the repo's directories for hooks, conf, and such. the repo's url is the http://. I understand you can make client side hooks with Tortoise, but I wanted to implement server-side hooks.

Any help would be great. I've looked over the internet and have read all the documentation, but I still don't quite get it.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place, my companies repositories were hidden away in a far different folder. Think I got mixed up with the idea of a directory vs. a repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need access to the (Server) Filesystem where your Repository is hosted.
The Repository Files structure looks like this:

- conf
- db
- hooks  <-- HERE we go!!
- locks
- format
- README.txt

There you find a directory called "hooks". Inside are a number of example files: Place an executable file with the correct name (see examples) and you are ready to go.

Comment: I have access to the Server where my repo is hosted, but I can't find the hooks directory. So did I create the repo incorrectly? I was told to just view the repo browser in TortoiseSVN and create a folder to make a repo. Is that correct?

Comment: No that is absolute not correct. By doing this you create a folder _inside_ your repository. I added the filestructure of a repository